# Margin adjusted but block is not

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue with some pages on a site. They all use the same code (index.php), including content from a text file.

The footer on the homepage is fine, and most inside pages.
http://dev.epicwebdesign.ca/korokriver/?page=home

Some, however, look like this:
http://dev.epicwebdesign.ca/korokriver/?page=mikwanwest

The best way can describe it, is the -17px margin is moving the footer up, but not shrinking the #site block on some pages, but working fine on others.

When inspecting the code with chrome, it's as if the block is jutting out from the rest. I have no idea how this is happening.

It has something to do with the height of the copy div. If it is set to 100% height, it looks fine. `min-height:100%` only works sometimes.

The blue is the block, the orange is the margin. They should be level.

[image]

This is what it should look like
[image]

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with the footer (assuming that table at the bottom is the footer) on either page. Maybe circle/arrow the problem on a screenshot and post the image? Also, post the code (just snippets needed to recreate the problem) so that this question can still be useful once your demo site is down.

Comment: How about instead of having the table outside of #site, you put it inside, with position absolute? That way, you don't have to worry about the negative margin. By the way, in FF it looks fine, so I'm not sure why it's not working in Chrome.

Comment: I uploaded screenshots. Strange, i'd expect it would work in Chrome and FF. It must be some kind of bug. Absolute positioning worked.

Comment: Isn't it because of the scrollbar appearing on the right when the page is too long?

Comment: Just the opposite, the scrollbar appeared because of the problem. I ended up using absolute positoning instead, didn't have the issues in chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used absolute positioning. Answering own question so that this can be closed.